# Check if namedtuple with value x exists in list

Tags: python, list, namedtuple

I want to see if a namedtuple exists in a list, similar to:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
if 1 in numbers:
      do_stuff()
```

is there a pythonic (or not) way to do this? Something like:

```
 namedtuples = [namedtuple_1, namedtuple_2, namedtuple3]
 if (namedtuple with value x = 1) in namedtuples:
      do stuff()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

**Demo:**

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> A = namedtuple('A', 'x y')
>>> lis = [A(100, 200), A(10, 20), A(1, 2)]
>>> any(a.x==1 for a in lis)
True
>>> [getattr(a, 'x')==1 for a in lis]
[False, False, True]
```