# Python -- Checking a list of objects to see if any have a specific attribute values

Tags: python, list, object, attributes

Is there any way of checking through a list of objects to see if any of them have a specific value for an attribute (or attributes). Let's say you wanted a program to see if there were any cabinets in a list of cabinets that were 40 inches tall and 50 inches wide. Does python have a way of finding that?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413080/check-if-namedtuple-with-value-x-exists-in-list

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
object_with_specific_attribute = [obj for obj in object_list if obj.length == 40 and obj.width == 50]
```

Comment: OP's question doesn't necessarily request for a list of objects that satisfy the criteria -- You could probably get away with an `any(generator_expression)` if short-circuiting is desired and only a boolean result is required.

Comment: And a very trivial nitpick: I would rename it `objects_with_specific_attribute` (note, `objects`, not `object) to indicate that you have a sequence and not a scalar.